# The door to the washer has started to crack

Tags: washing-machine

This just happened after the door was opened.

Model number for the washer: GE WCVH6800J1MS.

The rest of the machine still works very well, is there any way to replace/repair the door instead of having to junk the entire machine?

Pic of the damage:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

It's a replaceable part. Looks like part number WH46X10159. Unfortunately it's discontinued by the manufacturer so you'll likely have to look for a used one. Thankfully it looks like there's a lot of them available used on the usual places such as eBay.

Comment: Consider checking several of the many online appliance parts retailers, too. They may have NOS (New Old Stock) items, or have a newer part number that is a direct replacement for the older one. Then again, they may not... Also, look for a replacement for just the hinge as well as a complete door assembly.

Comment: Looks like ore-owned are available on eBay for about $100 shipped.

Comment: @FreeMan I checked around the common online parts retailers and was not finding any NOS. What I did find was owners doing this repair who said it was the frame that broke, so I suspect it's a weak point when people lean on or kids hang on the door.

Comment: Yeesh! Sounds like a bad design. I'd investigate repairing/replacing the frame parts and getting someone who can weld to look at it and design a brace for the back side to strengthen it. Might be as simple as a sheet of 18 gauge steel tack welded to the inside to strengthen it where the hinge is, might need to be something more complex, depending on internal clearances...

Comment: It looks like the frame is pot metal. There's a lot of the doors available on eBay for relatively cheap, so I would not necessarily jump to it being a bad design. Usually when something is a bad design the supply of used parts will also be thin. That spot is subject to a lot of stress if anyone puts weight on the door.